# Как прекратить выполнение приложения у локальных пользователей, кроме текущего?

Tags: c#

Есть приложение, которое проверяет по таймингу папку на фтп и если находит более новую версию файлов в ней, чем у пользователя, то обновляет их на те что в папке фтп, но перед этим задаёт вопрос о желании пользователя обновиться. Так вот в чём проблема, пользователей на локальной машине много, программа запускается для каждого пользователя в авторане и начинает работать синхронно с запущенной у другого пользователя, из-за этого возникает множество ошибок, в том числе с обновлением файлов, т.к. обе программы будут обновлять одни и те же файлы. Отсюда вопрос как можно приостановить выполнение кода у других пользователей, кроме текущего?

Comment: Если направление обновления -- из FTP папки на клиента, то как бы не вижу проблемы что несколько пользователей скачивают одни и те же файлы -- это нормально для сервера. Или вы также обновляете файлы с клиента в FTP-папку?

Comment: @nzeemin, они копирую информацию в одну и ту же папку. при этом логи обновления\ошибок скидываются в sql server таблицы, записи дублируются в зависимости от количества запущенных копий программы на локальной машине, т.е. по 2-3 за раз

Comment: Вероятно, перед проверкой наличия обновления следует использовать примитив синхронизации, типа мьютекса. Лишь один экземпляр приложения сможет захватить его. Он и установит обновление. А когда другие экземпляры получат доступ к коду обновления (по очереди захватывая мьютекс), то найдут на фтп ту же версию, что уже установлена.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov у меня уже используется mutex, но он не работает для других пользователей, т.е. если выполнить код ниже, то mutex посчитает, что это единственная запущенная копия на локальной машине, хотя параллельно ей у другого пользователя уже запущена данная копия программы: instanceMutex = new Mutex(true, @"Local\" + Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetType().GUID.ToString(), out createdNew); 
            if (!createdNew)
            {
                instanceMutex = null;
                Current.Shutdown();
                return;
            }

Comment: Префикс `Local` нужно сменить на `Global`, чтобы мьютекс был виден во всех сессиях.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov огромное спасибо, вы действительно очень мне помогли, это решило мою проблему с запуском нескольких копий на одной локальной машине!

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, проще всего вот что:

1. Смиритесь с тем, что старые версии могут бежать бесконечно. Например, один из юзеров засаспендил свою сессию, и уехал в отпуск на полгода, когда он вернётся, его старая версия ещё будет бежать. Ну или требуйте перезагрузки для инсталляции, что само по себе фе.
2. Ставьте каждую версию параллельно со старой. У вас будет каталог с программой, а в нём подкаталоги с версиями.
3. Скачивайте и ставьте новую версию при помощи сервиса, бегущего от администраторской учётки. Вы избежите необходимости показа юзеру UAC-окон.
4. Когда новая версия скачана, поменяйте автозапуск на новую версию.
5. Имеет смысл так же отправить бегущим экземплярам сообщение о том, что доступна новая версия, чтобы они предложили юзеру перезапуск. Впрочем, не давите на юзера, он вполне может захотеть работать дальше с этой версией до конце сессии. (Меня, например, раздражает, если программа требует от меня обновиться вотпрямща.)

Comment: Обновиться программа посредством другой утилиты, которая "валит" все запущенные образы и запускает новую версию. Но есть другие файлы, которые нужно обновлять периодически и они могут быть заняты пользователем, поэтому нужно спросить у него можно ли их освободить, а пользователь уж сам решает нужно ему это или нет. Обновление приходит в виде zip, который нужно скопировать и распаковать, при таких действиях никаких окон UAC не появляется

Comment: @МихаилКабаков: Как это не появляется? У вас программа, надеюсь, стоит в Program Files, а не в локальном каталоге пользователя или `C:\MyProg`, доступном каждому вирусу на запись? Для доступа из-под юзеровской учётки в Program Files нужно UAC.

Comment: всё гораздо проще, мы дали полные права для доступа к этой папке для всех юзверей)

Comment: @МихаилКабаков: Угу, и это ужасно. Это зияющая дыра. Для всех юзеров = для всех вирусов. Если один юзер подцепит вирус, вирус проникнет через вашу дыру ко всем пользователям.

Comment: не понимаю в чём может быть проблема расшаривания доступа для всех юзверей, мы же не даём им какие-то права администратора, мы просто разрешаем им запись и чтение в этой папке, тот же вирус с тем же успехом мог бы скопироваться в документы пользователя и с тем же успехом запуститься там и это будет куда проще релизовать, чем искать папку в program files, где есть возможность прописаться юзверю...

Comment: @МихаилКабаков: Смотрите. Если программа лежит в Program Files, то любой вирус, подхваченный одним юзером, останется только у этого юзера, т. к. он не сможет прописаться в каталог программы. Если каталог доступен на запись, тогда сможет. Хуже того, если каталог доступен юзеру на запись, он может просто заменить программу на троян или самописный вредонос, и другие юзеры запустят его и заразятся. С программой в недоступном юзеру для записи месте такое не произойдёт. (Вот почему каталог Program Files доступен лишь на чтение.)

Comment: спасибо, я честно говоря не подумал об этом, надеюсь наши админы учли этот момент, раз уж сказали мне сделать обработку именно таким образом

Comment: @МихаилКабаков: Угу, это по сути больше проблема админов, чем ваша.